# Is there a way to find the number of iterations that happened in a ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this requirement where on a html page I create some boxes(Flowchart generation) and every second box generated should have a different color.

I would like to know if there is a way to identify number of iterations that happened in a ng-repeat.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that use `ng-class-even` & `ng-class`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class-even="evenClass" ng-class-odd="oddClass">
     {{item.name}}
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
.evenClass {
   background: green;
}

.oddClass {
   background: blue;
}
```

Comment: There you go, even better.

Comment: @Lex thanks, I like your initial efforts too with CSS.

Comment: @MukundGandlur Glad to know that.. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

`$index` is automatically generated when using `ng-repeat` and is a zero-based iterator index.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}} ({{$index}})</li>
</ul>
```

*Note: there's probably a way to accomplish what you are after using CSS as well.*

Comment: `ng-class="{ 'diff-color-css-class' : $index%2 == 0 }"` perhaps on the li element

Comment: @LukeHutton I was thinking maybe even `nth-child(even)` and `nth-child(odd)` selectors.

Comment: yah even better built in